# Stop ScrollTop function when user scrolls jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i stop the scrollTop function when the user scrolls himself? If i scroll now while the scrollTop function the whole scrolling glitches out.

```
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $(".header-arrow-down").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".page-1").offset().top
                }, 1000);
            });
            $("body").scroll(function() {
                alert("scrolling");
            });
        });
```

I tried this so far but the alert scrolling isnt showing up for me and i can't find a solution on google so im asking it here.

I hope someone knows how to fix this thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you need to unbind or stop the animation when user scrolls, sth like

```
$("html, body").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
    $('html, body').stop();
});
```

Comment: nice, glad it helped, also this has been asked often before, if you had searched properly you found this yourself ;-D

Comment: Then i probally typed something wrong into google couldn't find anyone with the same problem yet :p

Comment: Oh you were faster ^^ +1

Answer (score 2):

**Hey I just wrote that code today for a project I'm working on:**

```
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel"){
    $("html,body").stop();
    }
});
```