# Animated scroll with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How is it possible to make the text **I am not clickable for some reason...** (check the code below) clickable?

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

var clickMe = document.querySelector('.clickMe');
clickMe.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');

    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".container").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

container.addEventListener('wheel', function() {
    var scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollY == 0) {
      $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".nextContainer").offset().top
      }, 800);
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="clickMe">'wheel'</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="nextContainer">
  <p class="clickMe">I am not clickable for some reason...</p>
</div>
```

As you see, the Wheel-listener works perfectly, while the click-listener does not. How do I solve this problem, if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appear because you get only first clickable element here :
 `var clickMe = document.querySelector('.clickMe');`

So, you attach the click event just at first element "wheel" text.
The solution to fix this problem is to get all ".clickMe" elements with [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp) and attach click event to each element.

```
var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.clickMe'); 
clickMe[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');

    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
clickMe[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');

    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work with this solution, can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: I used JQuery:s `stop()` function and it worked, will check your solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not clickable. In function which handle paragraph click add console.log("CLICKED"); and see in console if anything appears when you click. And in css add style for clickMe cursor:pointer; so when you hover it looks better.

Comment: The click-listener works, but the animation does not.. @sirius

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem.

After the animation,

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
  scrollTop: $(".nextContainer").offset().top
}, 800);
```

I needed to add JQuery:s `stop()` function,

`$('html, body').stop();`

Credits: [Stop ScrollTop function when user scrolls jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379182/stop-scrolltop-function-when-user-scrolls-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.querySelector('.clickMe')` you can use the jQuery Selector `$('.clickMe')`.
Than it works fine.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

var clickMe = document.querySelector('.clickMe');
console.log(clickMe);
$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');

    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".container").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

container.addEventListener('wheel', function() {
    var scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollY == 0) {
      $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".nextContainer").offset().top
      }, 800);
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="clickMe">'wheel'</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="nextContainer">
  <p class="clickMe">I am not clickable for some reason...</p>
</div>
```